# How to decide on picking new micro service or add to existing micro service when new business feature is requested

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, microservices, spring-ws, go-restful

I like to understand better on Micro services. Is there checklist which help me to decide particular new feature can be build as new micro service or combine with existing micro services available in my application?

Comment: Its called governance and no you make the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head, these are the questions I would try to answer:

1. Does the feature operate on the same data (in the same domain) as existing service?
2. Will the feature be managed and maintained by team that already covers existing service?
3. Will the feature need to scale according to the scaling of existing service (vs will have completely different scaling needs)?
4. Will the feature require a technology stack that is the same (vs completely
   different) as existing service?
5. Will the feature have the same change velocity as existing service?
6. Are all the security requirements the same in the new feature as in existing service?

The more 'Yes' answers, the more I would consider adding this feature to existing service.